# How to use BehaviorTestKit to verify the right child was spawned

Tags: scala, akka-typed

I'm trying to test determine that my actor spawned a child with the right parameters.

There is

```
testKit.expectEffect(Spawned(behavior,name,props))
```

But it's impossible to match since any behavior created inside your spawning behavior will never match a copy you create since behaviors only provide reference based equality.

Alternatively there is

```
testKit.expectEffectPF()
```

This let's you can at capture the behavior, but once again the reference is entirely opaque to inspection.

Short of providing some child builder function for the behavior under test that can then be mocked and inspected for its call signature, there doesn't seem to be a way to do this with the effect tooling provided by `BehaviorTestKit`.

Comment: Would `val spawnedResult = testKit.expectEffectType[Spawned]` help? Then you could match by result properties.

Answer (score 1):

Try using expectEffectType(Spawned[T])

Comment: Hey can you explain the context of that link? Might be useful to edit it into your answer if it is necessary.

Comment: Can you put some pseudocode that show the idea, please? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the ActorRef to the Spawned child one doesn't seem to be able to use *expectedEffected* instead one need to use *expectEffectType*

Say you want to test an Actor that spawns a child and then watches it, it would be something like the below

```
    val childActorDef = Behaviors.receiveMessage[Any] { _ =>
      Behaviors.same
    }
    val childId                                        = "ChildActor"
    
    val testKit: BehaviorTestKit[StartStopper.Command] = BehaviorTestKit(ActorUnderTest.actorDef)    

    testKit.run(ActorUnderTest.StartChildAndWatch(childActorDef, childId))
    val childSpawn : Spawned[Any] = testKit.expectEffectType[Spawned[Any]]
    val childRef : ActorRef[Any] = childSpawn.ref
    testKit.expectEffect(Watched[Any](childRef.ref))
```